# I need a word in the sense of “to category”

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need a word that fits this case:
I have a book; and any User may apply some tags to it, like 'dark' or 'happy' [..]
Anyway, how would I call this action, using a *short term*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the internet, it's usually called "tagging".

Answer (score 16):

Are you looking for ***categorize***?

> transitive verb
>
> to place into a category : *classify*

Comment: +1 Very precise, but i shall take @Chisti's for context

Comment: Haha, until I saw your response I nearly edited the OP's title to change 'category' to 'categorize' :)